# Connect two pods to the same external access point

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have two pods (deployments) running on minikube. Each pod has the same port exposed (say 8081), but use different images. Now I want to configure so that I can access either of the pods using the same external URL, in a load balanced way. So what I tried to do is put same matching label in both pods and map them to same service and then expose through NodePort. Example:

```
#pod1.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dep1
  labels:
    apps: dep1
    tier: cloud
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: dep1-pod
      labels:
        app: deployment1
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: cont1
          image: cont1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:deployment1
```

Now second pod

```
#pod2.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dep2
  labels:
    apps: dep2
    tier: cloud
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: dep2-pod
      labels:
        app: deployment1
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: cont2
          image: cont2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:deployment1
```

Now the service:

```
#service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30169
  selector:
    app: deployment1
```

Now this does not work as intended as it refuses to connect to my IP:30169. However, I can connect if only one of the pods are deployed.
Now I know I can achieve this functionality using replicas and just one image, but in this case, I want to do this using 2 images. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try with `selector` `tier: cloud` in you service...you can also use `minikube tunnel` to emulate services of type `LoadBalancer`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to achieve it.

> - Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.
> - An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting.
> - An Ingress controller is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic.
> - An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type  `Service.Type=NodePort`  or  `Service.Type=LoadBalancer`.

In your situation `Ingress` will forward traffic to your services using the same URL. It depends which path you type: URL for first `Pod` and URL/v2 for second `Pod`. Of course you can change /v2 to something else.

On the beginning you need enable `Ingress` on `minikube`. You can do it using a command below. You can red more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#enable-the-ingress-controller)

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Next step you need create a `Ingress` using a yaml file. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#deploy-a-hello-world-app) is an example how to do it step by step.

Yaml file of `Ingress` looks as below.
As you can see in this configuration, you can access to one `Pod` using URL  and it will forward traffic to first service attached to the first `Pod`. For the second `Pod` using URL/v2 it will forward traffic to second service on attached to the second `Pod`.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /v2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web2
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: @ArnabGhosh does my answer is helpful for you?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I'm not sure this achieves what I wanted. Because here you have two paths URL and URL/v2. What I want is to access either of the pods using the same URL/path and same port.

Comment: @ArnabGhosh It makes no sense what you are trying to do. LoadBalancer is for split traffic for Pods which are the same. If you have 2 difference images you need to choose which you want to connect and that is why you should have URL with other paths